# Using Jquery with select tags

Tags: jquery

heres a fiddle to give you an idea of what im trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/g4ymr/13/

```
<a href="">Menu 1</a>
<a href="">Menu 2</a>
<a href="">Menu 3</a>
<a href="">Menu 4</a>

<select name="type1">
   <option value="1">Menu 1</option>
   <option value="2">Menu 2</option>
   <option value="2">Menu 3</option>
   <option value="2">Menu 4</option>
</select>
```

​

Menu 1 2 3 4 represents my main Navigation on my website....

when a user clicks menu 2 i want the select tag form to go to menu 2

menu 3 when the user clicks on menu 3

and so on

I'm very new to jquery so i need help getting started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g4ymr/14/)*

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $('select[name=type1] option').eq( $(this).index() ).prop('selected', true);
});
```

in this example I use the clicked *button*'s `.index()` to reference ( targeting `.eq()` ) the desired `option` element.
Hope I don't need to say you better use a more specific selector than just `a`. ...hmm I just said it :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the anchors href attribute to point to the option means that the back/forward buttons would change the option as well. May or may not be required but worth knowing:

http://jsfiddle.net/EUZb3/

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $("select[name=type1]").val($(this).attr("href").substring(1))
});​
```

Comment: Thats great!  Thank you!  But what if i want to go from one page to another and not on the same page?